# How did the children end up discovering the crop circles in the beginning?

Tags: signs

I ask because it seems rather mysterious. Usually in most crop circle accounts, it's the farmers who discover the circles, plowing their crops (I know, however, it's a movie but it's based on a real phenomena - crop circles). Here it seemed rather mysterious and horror movie-like.

How did the children end up discovering the circles? Is it that the dogs woke them up? I'm presuming the dogs knew the circles were being made and saw UFOs. Maybe I missed a line.

Comment: I haven't watched it (Mel Gibson in a tin foil hat, aliens for whom water is a poison trying to conquer the Earth - nope not watching that,) but kids on farms **play** in the fields.  Nothing mysterious about kids discovering the crop circles.

Comment: @JRE Actually the best "UFO experience in the green fields" that I had seen in some time, although in the second half it goes a bit sideways. Can't have everything. Don't hate on Mel Gibson.

Comment: Crop circles are indeed a real phenomena though - 100% manmade [Best of Crop Circles](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffsb&q=best+of+crop+circles&iax=images&ia=images)

Comment: I disagree, David, I think some crop circles are saucer landing nests or at least made by beams of saucers

Comment: I dont think it is anything more than the dogs led the kids there in the morning when they woke up. dogs were agitated from the crop circles the night before (presumably).

Answer (score 1):

According to [the script](https://sfy.ru/?script=signs_2002), the dogs were clearly agitated, Bo thought that she was dreaming, I do not think we got a definitive answer whether the dogs got them there or they (kids, dogs or both) were sleepwalking, abducted and left there memoryless.

M. Night Shyamalan has a really good talent in hiding the obvious in plain sight and leaving his movies open to interpretation.

> INT.  BATHROOM - MORNING
> A bathroom door is open.  WE HEAR THE SINK RUNNING.  WE HEAR
> THE SOUNDS OF TEETH BEING BRUSHED.
> Outside the bathroom on the bedroom wall is the sun faded
> outline of where a large CATHOLIC CROSS used to hang.  It's
> ghostly stained forever on the blank wall.
> A CHILD SCREAMS FROM FAR AWAY.
> The water from the sink stops.  Graham steps into the
> doorway.  Toothbrush and foam in his mouth.  He becomes very
> still.

then as he runs to their bedrooms, he finds the beds empty.

> The bedroom door bursts open.  Graham steps into his
> children's room.  There are children's books everywhere.
> Overflowing off shelves.  Piled in corners.
> Graham's eyes move to the small messy beds.  They're both
> empty.

He and his brother run towards the screaming

> Graham and Merrill in unison turn in the direction of the
> YELLING.  They look away from the house, across the yard and
> into THE THICK WALL OF CROPS.

As he finds Bo and she thinks that she is dreaming.

> BO: Are you in my dreams too?

He hears his son's voice

> Graham looks in the direction of THE BOY'S VOICE.  He's
> close.  Graham picks up Bo and rushes through the crops.
> He finds MORGAN standing with his hands in the pockets of his
> pajama bottoms.  DOGS ARE BARKING NEARBY.

As Morgan thinks the God did it.

then they discover the crop circles

> He walks through a thin layer of crops and emerges in a
> clearing.  Two German Shepherds are running back and forth.
> They are clearly agitated.